# Change image width on Java 

Tags: java, android, size, invisible

Hi I added this comment to the code to show a background when i press , but it show the image all is working except , the image is too small , but the image size correspond on the size of the device , how can i set the size , or force it to be

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg);
```

there is the full code

```
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        mTracking = true;
        mTriggered = false;
        vibrate();
        if (leftHit) {
            mCurrentSlider = mLeftSlider;
            mOtherSlider = mRightSlider;
            mThreshold = isHorizontal() ? THRESHOLD : 1.0f - THRESHOLD;
            setGrabbedState(OnTriggerListener.LEFT_HANDLE);
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg_right);
        } else {
            mCurrentSlider = mRightSlider;
            mOtherSlider = mLeftSlider;
            mThreshold = isHorizontal() ? 1.0f - THRESHOLD : THRESHOLD;
            setGrabbedState(OnTriggerListener.RIGHT_HANDLE);
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg_left);
        }                  
        mCurrentSlider.setState(Slider.STATE_PRESSED);
        mCurrentSlider.showTarget();
        mOtherSlider.hide();
        break;
    }
}
```

cheers

Comment: have you tried setPadding? or setLayoutParams?

Comment: i am new on java , and pasted so many time just to make that , so i havent trayed another method than this, but learned somewer that with layoutparams is possible , can you provideme a exemple code cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'll post you a small example, feel free to adjust to your needs:

```
int width = 1024;
int height = 768;
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainframe);

fl.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

If you want you can use match_parrent instead of width and height ofc, or anything else that xml can do

Comment: thanks , as i see on findViewById(R.id.mainframe) , i need to add a id ? and a layout file ?

Comment: R.id.mainframe is my example, mainframe is the id of the layout I choose to set params on.

Comment: R.id.mainframe , i need to change mainframe by image ? , or is this specify a layout xml file , if yes i need to ad a entry on com?internal.R.id cheers

Comment: yes, either you use it on the image, or on the parent or both. if parent is wrap content, then image won't get much effect using fill parent or match parrent.

Comment: R.id.mainframe is a FrameLayout in my code, with children that needed to be that exact size. So I gave that width and height to the frame, and made the children match the parrent's width/height

Comment: what do you mean, need to be changed? you can set parameters on them by the code i provided to make it larger

Comment: or just use it on the parent of the view, and let the image view match his parent

Comment: thanks for your help , but i have some trouble, findViewById(R.id.image); the R.id.image need to be changed , by what? cause i have setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg); , and want to set him size , so i need to do somethink that for exemple the mainframe call the slider_bg , and set it to android.internal.id , how ? , no another way to do for exemple , slider_bg = and call a xml on layout folder , so i can add a xml adding on it the size etc , cheers

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the problem you describe, could you rephrase please? :)

Comment: int width = 480; int height = 854; FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
        fl.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg); is this corret ? , but mainframe , he cant find it , i trayed to change it by background wut i have wlod on the phone

Comment: hmm i think i knwo what is not correct we set frame size , but dont say on whet image it need to be set so it do it for all the image he finde , this is exact ? , do i need to add after the setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg) this " { " , and close it after the layout parametre ?

Comment: The frame should be the image's parent, if the frame is larger, and the child matches it's parent, the view will be larger.

Comment: i cant change the findViewById(R.id.mainframe);  with this findViewById(R.drawable.slider_bg); ?

Comment: so there is what ive trayed : added on values/ids.xml the mainframe entry , and your code , compilation succesfull , but the phone bootloop , trayed to change the mainframe to background but again bootlop

Comment: i understand the prencipe but as i havent developped on java yet , i cant make it

Comment: or can i do somethink like this , like we sayd we set playout height and weight , is this not possible like this ?         int width = 480; int height = 854 {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg);
        };